# Bootstrap 3 getting labels to stay on top of input fields

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to have 3 form input fields in a row with their respective labels on the top. When the row wraps I want the labels to go with the corresponding input and stay on top. I can get the labels to appear to the left of the input fields just fine. Just not on top of the input. How can this be achieved

Comment: Add the related html, css and any javascript code to your question and if possible add a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to your question

Answer (score 0):

Working with colums should do the trick. Try something like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <label>Label 1</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <label>Label 2</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <label>Label 3</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-4">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use col-md-4 because Bootstrap is built on a 12 col grid system. That way on small and extra small devices the coloumns automatically collapse down to a single row. Here's my pen.

```
http://www.bootply.com/Eb85k7lOAx
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>One</label>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder=".col-md-4" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Two</label>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder=".col-md-4" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Three</label>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder=".col-md-4" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```